# JPA Multiple OneToMany relations to the same Entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I am trying to build a JPA Application. I basically have

```
@Entity
public class Folder {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  private int id;
  private String description;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<AbstractItem> items = new LinkedList<AbstractItem>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<AbstractItem> items2 = new LinkedList<AbstractItem>();
  .
  .
  .
}
```

i can successfully add one Item to the `item` List, and persist it. However if i load it again, the same Object of the persistet Item is in both Lists `items` and `items2`.

I tried to fix this by adding a `@JoinTable` annotation, but i couldn't get it to work.

any suggestions?

Comment: Theres a code smell here (the duplicate mapping and near duplicate variable name). *What are you really trying to accomplish?*

Comment: that was just a small example to clarify the problem. The actual setting in which i encountered the Problem would be to big to post here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have two references to the 'Folder' in your AbstractItem, for each case. Thus, mappedBy values should be specified accordingly, e.g.:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<AbstractItem> items = new LinkedList<AbstractItem>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent2", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<AbstractItem> items2 = new LinkedList<AbstractItem>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mappedBy` attribute is linking to a unique property named `parent` of `AbstractItem`, in other words, you are linking `AbstractItem` and `Folder` by the same attribute.
If you map the second list as `parent2`, there will be 2 foreign keys in `AbstractItem` to `Folder` table. 
Use two associative tables (for `items` and `items2`) if you don't want a new property and a new column in `AbstractItem`.